# What is the "this" keyword pointing to when call and apply is nested in a function?

Tags: javascript, this, call

```
// global scope

var sayMyFavoriteColor = function(adj){
    return 'My ' + adj + ' color is ' + this.favoriteColor; + '!'
};

var callFnTest = function (opts) {
  return sayMyFavoriteColor.call(this, opts);
};

this.favoriteColor = 'Brown'; //adding a global variable to window
i.e. var favoriteColor = 'Brown'

callFnTest('most disliked')
"My most disliked color is Brown"
```

My question is because we are passing `this` to call it is pointing to the window, correct?

Comment: @KenY-N My apologies!

Comment: In your example, `this` inside `sayMyFavoriteColor` refers whatever `this` is inside `callFnTest`. Since it is called as `callFnTest(...)`, `this` will refer to the global object, or `undefined` if strict mode is enabled. I recommend to read an article about `this` (such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) if you haven't yet.

Comment: @FelixKling So one should just zero in on  the `return sayMyFavoriteColor.call(this, opts);` statement. In other words if we had an object with a property `favoriteColor : 'Plaid'` in the context in place of our hard coded `this` reference. The color would be Plaid? RIght?

Comment: Yes. The first argument passed to `.call` becomes the `this` value of the function that `.call` is called on.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change. You can only use the this keyword when you use an instance of the class. Basically, if you call `a.whateverFunction()`, `a` is `this`.